# Datagridviewss and Threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview

I want to update a datagridview from a thread using VB.

I have tried two approaches so far, but clearly I am missing something.  The two methods are:

```
If Control.invokeRequired Then
    Control.Invoke(Sub() Control.rows.add(Event*Date, Event*Details))
```

And I have tried:

```
If Control.InvokeRequired then
    Control.Invoke(New Addrow(AddressOf Form1.AddToDatatable), New Object() {Data_row})
```

Where

```
Public Delegate Sub Addrow(ByVal Data_row As DataRow)
   Public Sub AddToDatatable(ByVal Data_row As DataRow)
       Data_table.Rows.Add(Data_row)
       Daily_Log.Refresh()
   End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? What happens when you use that code? Does it compile? If not, what's the error message? If so, does it run? If not, what's the error message? If so, what actually happens that you don't expect or doesn't happen that you do expect? Please provide ALL the relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your suggestions. I wrote my question in abject frustration on Thursday after spending a day reading forums trying to find out what was going on. Friday afternoon I eventually worked it out.

Two things led to me finding a solution.

1. I could not work out why invokerequired was always returning false. I initially assumed this was because I was running in debug to watch the code. In frustration I removed the invokerequired and let the code go to the invoke. This was the best thing I could have done even though it threw an error. Something about the form event not created
2. This made me wonder about the form and the control so I added some debug code on isdisposed and eventcreated. Both returned false.

Yet the form was sitting in front of my eyes waiting for data...

It then occurred to me that maybe, just maybe I was not able to address the displayed form at all from the thread.
In desperation I decided to add the form to the thread initiation and receive the form as a parameter when the thread initiated.

Omg! It worked. Invokerequired suddenly turned true and the invoke worked without error and data started appearing on my form, cracked it!

They say hard learning is not forgotten quickly, and I doubt I'll forget this quickly.

In summary when initiating the thread, pass the live form as the sole parameter and in your thread reference the passed form, not the from directly... Grrr.
I hope me posting this helps save someone else from tearing their hair out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a `DataTable` bound to a `DataGridView`. In that case, you need to add the data to the `DataTable`. `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` are instance members of the `Control` class, so need to be accessed via a control reference. If you know the code is being executed on a secondary thread then using `InvokeRequired` is pointless. I suspect that your code should be like this:

```vb
myDataGridView.Invoke(Sub() myDataTable.Rows.Add(someValue, someOtherValue))
```

Your would only need to use `InvokeRequired` if the code is in a method that might be executed on the UI thread or a secondary thread. For instance, you might do this:

```vb
Private Sub AddRow(column1Value As Object, column2Value As Object)
    If myDataGridView.InvokeRequired Then
        myDataGridView.Invoke(New Action(Of Object, Object)(AddressOf AddRow), column1Value, column2Value)
    Else
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(column1Value, column2Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

You can then just call that method anywhere and it will handle the rest. You can do this on a secondary thread:

```vb
AddRow(someValue, someOtherValue)
```

On that call, `InvokeRequired` will be `True`, so a delegate will be created for the same `AddRow` method nad passed to `Invoke`, along with the parameter values. `Invoke` will cross the thread boundary and invoke `AddRow` a second time. This time `InvokeRequired` will be `False`, so the row will be added to the `DataTable`.